# Change NaN to 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code that return to me result of javascript average function in bootstrap modal. But when one of inputs are blank, he return NaN . How i can change NaN to 0?

Here is my code that return result:

```
 $(".average").click(function () {
 var result = average();
 $("#myModal .modal-body h2").text(result);
 $("#myModal").modal();
 });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check whether a value is `NaN` using the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function:

```
var result = average();
if (isNaN(result)) result = 0;
```

---

In the future, when ECMAScript 6 is widely available one may consider switching to [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), as `isNaN` does not properly handle strings as parameters.

> In comparison to the global `isNaN` function, `Number.isNaN` doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number. This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert to `NaN`, but aren't actually the same value as `NaN`. This also means that only values of the type `number`, that are also `NaN`, return `true`.

Compare:

```
isNaN("a"); // true
Number.isNaN("a"); // false
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not just OR, this is one of the most common ways to set a "fallback" value

```
var result = average() || 0;
```

as `null`, `undefined` and **NaN** are all falsy, you'd end up with `0`, just be aware that `0` is also falsy and would in this case also return `0`, which shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = average();
result = (isNaN(result) ? 0 : result); //ternary operator check the number is NaN if so reset the result to 0
```

Use `isNaN` function.

Comment: Might be worth explaining what how a ternary operator works.